# Мандарины, не меньшие(,) чем

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли мною обрамлённая запятая?

*Вам надо найти мандарины на базаре, не меньшие(,) чем те, которые мы позавчера-таки купили.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Указанная запятая нужна, она ставится по следующему правилу.

> [**(НЕ) МЕНЕЕ / МЕНЬШЕ, ЧЕМ,** *в составе сравнительного оборота*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_415&layout=item)
>
> Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются два сравниваемых понятия.